# P points and Q points

Tags: general-topology, logic

I'm looking at the definition of p points here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/P-point. I've also seen the definition of p points and q points given in terms of ultrafilters, here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62312/is-every-p-point-ultrafilter-ramsey. I was wondering if anyone could interpret this definition of q points in terms a elements of the underlying compact Hausdorff space $X$, for the space $C(X)$, as in the first link. Also, given the continuum hypothesis, is there a theorem that shows the existence of points that are both p and q points (Ramsey ultrafilters)?

Comment: Theorem 7.8 in Jech's book is exactly your second question: if CH holds, there is a Ramsey ultrafilter